# User clicks link in email, it opens email client, how to close window/tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

A user clicks a link in their HTML email, it then goes to a page that simply opens up their email client.

```
 window.location.href = 'mailto:...';
```

I don't want this window/tab to stay open, how can I close it?

`window.close()` doesn't work since it wasn't opened using window.open()

is it possible?

Comment: ok, you're rigth, I didn't see it was an HTML email and thought you mean a page... so, I don't understand, where do you call window.location.href = 'mailto:...';?

Answer (score 1):

The browser does not control the mail client, period. It launches an APPLICATION, not a window.

Comment: yes, but I want the window/browser that launches the application to close after it launches the application.

Comment: If browsers had control over other applications, we'd be in big trouble. It would be a serious security breach.

Comment: But I'm not even asking the browser to control other applications.  I am asking for the browser to close itself once the other application launches. window.close() that's all (which doesn't work).

Comment: You cannot close a browser using script that was not opened using script. I certainly would NEVER want a web site to be closing MY browser.

Comment: window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close(); works in IE, so it is possible.

Comment: @Blankman, yeah actually it's possible but work only with IE. I think there would be an equivalent for window.close in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Diodeus: using a `mailto:` link opens an external application which you cannot control via your browser. Even if you could close the window that a web email application loaded, you can't guarantee everyone would launch a webmail app on a `mailto:` link. Some of us use Exchange/Outlook at work, for example.

If you really want to control the user experience of sending an email from your application, skip `mailto:` links altogether and offer a page/form that allows the user to enter the email body/subject.

You then process the form and send the email using whatever server-side technology you're using. This can have the benefit of not exposing your email address to spambots.

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_window = window.open(mailto:foo@bar.com");
new_window.close();
```

That's what you want.

Comment: That's not what he wants. He wants the browser window/tab that opened the mail app to close, and not for the mail app/window to close.