# JS: Can't close current window/tab after email client pops up

Tags: javascript

Edited: I took a look at: [User clicks link in email, it opens email client, how to close window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699401/user-clicks-link-in-email-it-opens-email-client-how-to-close-window-tab)

Just want to confirm, is there really no way to do it.

---

My page acts as a "transition/intermediate page", it would either redirect to other page, or open email client.

"#myDiv" contains a link, it might be a normal link (eg: http://www) or an email link (mailto:).The link is coming from DB.
What I wanted to do is:

1. Detect whether it is a normal link or email link.
2. If it is a normal link, redirect the page to that link.
3. If it is a mailto link, open that email client (eg: outlook), then close the current window/tab.

I got 1 and 2 working, but for 3, i could have the email client (ooutlook) come out. But It just didn't close the current window/tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div id="myDiv">
    <a href="mailto:test@test.com">Here is a email address. This window/tab should be closed.</a>
</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var link = jQuery("#myDiv a").attr("href");
        if(link.indexOf("mailto:") == -1) {
            window.location = link;
        } else {
            opener=self;
            //alert('in else');
            window.location = link;
            self.close();
            window.close();
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can't close the window if you didnt open it(using window.open for example).